# Getting unknown user signups after every push to Play store internal release track

Tags: android, google-play, spam, google-play-console

I'm currently building an android app and I'm using the Play store's internal test track to send builds out to myself and a friend.

After each push to the internal test track, I notice strange signups in Firebase Authentication (which handles my user creations).

Other than the fact that I am most certain none of my (2) test users created those accounts, the emails used are kindof... suspicious ?
With a bit of searching I found some of them in publicly accessible email lists or even pastebins of email leaks.

I have disabled the pre-launch reports from the Play console to make sure it wasn't the google bots but it's still happening.

Where are those users/bots coming from ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Seems like google's bots, but I can't be sure. EDIT: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911115/fake-users-in-firebase-with-gmail-com-accounts

Comment: @RicardoRomeroBenítez: Did not. As suggested by Doug in your own post, I contacted the Firebase support, but they weren't really able to help. I've ended up changing my registration scheme to only use magic sign in links to avoid all those spam signups. Sending email verifications on google accounts might help as well I guess.

Comment: this may help you

https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/android-studio#modify_instrumented_test_behavior_for

Comment: Mmh, I don't think that was the cause of the signups, I've never used the Firebase Test lab (and disabled the Play Console's pre-launch tests).