# Fake users in firebase with @gmail.com accounts

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase project.
The next sign-in methods auth are enabled:

- Google
- Facebook
- Apple
- Anonymous

A mobile app interacts with the firebase.

Each day I get some weird new users sign-ups with fake accounts with the pattern: [name][numbers]@gmail.com. They don't do anything except sign up via google oauth once.

Is it possible to prevent it? Maybe I missed something with the google oauth configuration?

**Updated:**

Also, I noticed that these sign-ups started to occur when I had sent out the mobile app to google/apple verification. May these two events are correlated?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find out why?

Comment: @diegocom I've found some weird correlation with Apple builds. I think Apple uses some automation to check SSO. I asked Apple support but they refused to provide any details. Firebase support also refused to provide IP addresses. So I can't prove that is Apple because I haven't direct evidence.

Comment: I think so too, these accounts appeared after I requested build approval from Apple and never reached the HomePage after login so they are probably bot users for social login verification

Comment: Same. Fake gmail users logging every day. It might be google bots but besides being annoying having this increasing fake account, the question is does google charge us for all these users? does it count for example againt the authentication quota?

Answer (score 4):

New accounts created coz of Play market [Pre Launch Report](https://play.google.com/console/about/pre-launchreports/)

You can change Pre Launch Report settings to change it's behaviour (e.g. specify test account to use in auth)

[image: Pre Launch Report Settings]

Comment: I checked this version too but all accounts there has @cloudtestlabaccounts.com domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure those fake users have a specific pattern from their email address, I would make a trigger function on Cloud Functions for Firebase.

You can use [`functions.auth.user().onCreate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation) event handler like below.

```
exports.checkFakeUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // You can check if the user has suspicious email patterns and delete them here.
});
```

Or you can also make a [Schedule function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) on Cloud Functions for Firebase and daily check if there are fake users and automatically delete them.

Plus, it would be a good step if you figure out that fake users still joining even you didn't expose your mobile app anywhere if you want to find out the reason how they are joining.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following Cloud Function will help you on check the email and delete the fake user

```
    exports.checkFakeUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
        const list = user.email.split(".")[1].split("@")
        const isFake = list[0].length === 5 && list[1] === 'gmail'
        if(isFake){
            admin.auth().deleteUser(user.uid)
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop specific accounts from being created, as the underlying Google Auth APIs are accessible to anyone with an account.  You could manually delete them, or write a program to delete them (bearing in mind that you could also be deleting actual user accounts).

Or if you suspect abusive behavior, you can [contact Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to report that.

Comment: So is this a usual case for firebase project when even "unknown" project experiences sign ups from fake accounts? Also, I noticed that these sign-ups started to occur when I had sent out the mobile app to google verification. But I'm not sure about this. May these two events are correlated?

Comment: I don't know what is "usual".  I'd recommend contacting Firebase support for clarification.

Comment: @DougStevenson, as said above and after checking when pushing my 2 apps into Play Store, this unknown connection happens only after a release of new version to Play Store but even when we are in Internal Testing mode so the Auth PI  accessible to anyone,  doesnt seems the reason. This seems to be an inside job.

Answer (score 0):

Check, these e-mail addresses will be re-logged when they upload a new version to google play. The most likely reason for this is that google keeps your application to a number of tests with its automation infrastructure.